# C++ Passing Objects by Reference

Tags: c++, object, reference

I am trying to learn C++, and I am working through "Sams Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days".

I have been progressing quite well so far, and even got through the chapter on pointers without difficulty. However, a listing on "Passing Objects by Reference" has left me quite confused.

There is a class with two constructors:

```
class SimpleCat
{
public :
    SimpleCat();
    SimpleCat(SimpleCat&);
...
};
```

two functions with the prototype:

```
SimpleCat FunctionOne( SimpleCat theCat );
SimpleCat* FunctionTwo( SimpleCat *theCat );
```

*/* What is confusing me is that when calling the second function, the second constructor `SimpleCat(SimpleCat&);` is called. Could someone please explain? Any further searching has left me equally confused. */*

**EDIT:** I have made a mistake in my post here, the copy constructor (as I now know what it is, thank-you so much ) is called with the first function. I am sorry for the confusion. I know understand the link now and you have all helped tremendously.

Comment: Could you add more code?  I would expect the SimpleCat(SimpleCat&) constructor to be called for FunctionOne and NOT FunctionTwo.

Comment: For the record, any book that claim that they can teach you C++ in days is just garbage. IMHO C++ is a very complex language and implying it can be learned in a few days is just ... dangerous.

Comment: Please post the content of FunctionOne and FunctionTwo: most likely the call to your copy constructor is done somewhere in the body, and not in the call itself.

Comment: @Anders K.: it teaches you how to program in C++, it doesn't teach you how to programm *well* in C++ :)

Comment: @Anders Amen to that. The book should be called "Get something to syntactically pass compilation in 21 days". I have been working with C++ to and fro during 10 years and still consider myself a newbie. I doubt there are more than a handful of people in the whole world that actually know every single picky detail of the language.

Comment: to @Matthew & @Anders: "Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years" http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleCat(SimpleCat&)` is a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor). `SimpleCat FunctionOne(SimpleCat theCat)` uses [pass by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) semantics. This requires that the class instance be copied. Hence the call to the copy constructor.

Comment: He claims that the copy constructor is called upon calling the second function...

Comment: @Greg Well, an empty function with that signature wouldn't call the copy constructor. So, my assumption is that @Matthew misstated the problem. I don't see why that merits a down vote.

Comment: you are entirely correct, I posted incorrrectly. Thank-you for your (and to everyone else) for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. As you can see [here](http://www.ideone.com/Lpn5S) the copy-constructor is only called when you call `FunctionOne`.

**edit** including the code directly here so that it is easier to read.

**source:**

```
#include <iostream>

class SimpleCat {
    public:
        SimpleCat() {
            std::cout << "\tSimpleCat() called\n";
        }

        SimpleCat(SimpleCat&) {
            std::cout << "\tSimpleCat(SimpleCat&) called\n";
        }
};

SimpleCat FunctionOne( SimpleCat theCat ){
    return theCat;
}

SimpleCat* FunctionTwo( SimpleCat* theCatPtr ){
    return theCatPtr;
}

int main() {
    SimpleCat cat;
    std::cout << "-----\n";

    std::cout << "FunctionOne{\n";
    FunctionOne(cat);
    std::cout << "}\n";

    std::cout << "FunctionTwo{\n";
    FunctionTwo(&cat);
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

**output**:

```
    SimpleCat() called
-----
FunctionOne{
    SimpleCat(SimpleCat&) called
    SimpleCat(SimpleCat&) called
}
FunctionTwo{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor that takes a reference to it's own type is called a "copy constructor" (that will be in your book).

Whenever the compiler needs to make a copy of an object of certain type, if the class definition has a copy-constructor it will use that, otherwise it uses a default implementation that it provides. So the copy constructor allows you to take control of how your class is copied.

Most likely your copy constructor is being used when you call `FunctionOne`, not `FunctionTwo` because the parameter is being passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

Your FunctionOne takes an object BY VALUE.
That means, that whenever the function is called, a copy is made of the datatype. This holds for ordinary datatypes like int, char, ..., but also for objects (in your case a SimpleCat object).
So when you have a function like `void doIt(int a)`, then when you call doIt(3), the value 3 is copied by *creating a new instance* of an integer with the value of 3.
Translated to your `FunctionOne`, calling `FunctionOne(cat)` will make a *copy* of your cat object, resulting in the copy constructor being called.